# Picking up values with puppeteer and playing and playing on an html page

Tags: javascript

I'm using puppeteer to get data and then I'm creating a website that uses this collected information.

I made two files a javascript

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const xlsx = require("xlsx");


(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.ibge.gov.br/explica/inflacao.php');

  const options = await page.$$eval('.variavel-dado', ipca => ipca.map((option) => option.innerHTML));
  const htmlList = options.map( dado =>`<a>"dado"<a>` )
  document.querySelector('ipca').innerHTML = htmlList;





})();
```

and another html

```
title>PROJECT | Dashboard AÇÕES BETA</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div class="title-box">
        <h1 class="title">Dashboard</h1>
        <p>INFORMAÇÕES AQUI</p>
      </div>

      <div class="toggle-mode">
        <span>Dark Mode</span>
        <input type="checkbox" class="btnToggle">
      </div>
    </header>

    <main>
      <section class="followers">
        <article class="card facebook">
          <span class="username">
            <img src="./images/icon-facebook.svg" alt="facebook">
            @elianbecali
          </span>
          <p class="count-follow">
         
            Followers
          </p>
          <span>
            <img src="./images/icon-up.svg" alt="Up Followers">
            12 Today
          </span>
        </article>


        <article class="card twitter">
          <span class="username">
            <img src="./images/icon-twitter.svg" alt="facebook">
            @elianbecali
          </span>
          <p class="count-follow">
            <span >  
               <p class="ipca">
                   
                </p>
            </span>
            Followers
          </p>
          <span>
            <img src="./images/icon-up.svg" alt="Up Followers">
            
          </span>
        
      </section>
      
    </main>
  </div>

 

  <script src="./js/index.js" defer ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the information is in the html go in the "ipca" class.

follows the code below this code generates the information, I can see it in the console log, but I can't play in the html.

Comment: You could probably extract the information you are interested in using https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-repl, for including the plugin see the main page of the repo from the link.

Comment: I just opened the repository, I didn't understand it very well. If that's really what I need.